# How to join multiple subqueries in view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following simplified view. You can see that I have multiple subqueries on the same table. Is there a way to make it as one single sub-query? something like:

```
(select count(*), sum(..), max(..) from XY1 .....) as (Count1, Sum1, Max1),
(select count(*), sum(..), max(..) from XY2 .....) as (Count2, Sum2, Max2),
```

here is the code:

```
drop view if exists view_OffersStat;
create view view_OffersStat as

select
o.Id as Offer_Id,
o.Title,
o.Start,
o.Expires,

(select count(*) from Sale as s where s.Merchant_Id=o.Merchant_Id) as Total_Sales,
(select sum(s.Net) from Sale as s where s.Merchant_Id=o.Merchant_Id) as Total_Net,
(select sum(s.Gross)) from Sale as s where s.Merchant_Id=o.Merchant_Id) as Total_Gross,
(select max(s.Gross) from Sale as s where s.Merchant_Id=l.Merchant_Id) as Max_Gross,

from Offer as o;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop view if exists view_OffersStat;
create view view_OffersStat as

select
o.Id as Offer_Id,
o.Title,
o.Start,
o.Expires,
count(*) as Total_Sales,
sum(s.Net) as Total_Net,
sum(s.Gross) as Total_Gross,
max(s.Gross) as Max_Gross,

from Offer as o
inner join Sale as s
on s.Merchant_Id=o.Merchant_Id
group by s.Merchant_Id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't work. for example Sale table has 350 rows but Total_Sales gives value 3800

Comment: how come? why Total_Sales gives value 3800?

Comment: my fault, I read it incorrectly, It all works if I change group by o.Id (offer, not sale) thanks for pointing me the right direction